# Redirect Print to statusbar

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to redirect text to status bar. Here I want to display a print to status bar.

It should look like this but it doesn't work:

```
import sys
import wx

class RedirectText:
    def __init__(self, statusbar):
        self.statusbar = statusbar
    def write(self,string):
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText(string)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        redirection = RedirectText(self.statusbar)
        sys.stdout = redirection
        print 'hello'
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    def OnClose(self, event):
        raise RuntimeError('error')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit unexpected, but the `write` function you defined will get called twice in your current code: first it will receive the "hello" string, then a newline. Because the newline isn't visible in your statusbar, it looks like nothing was updated.

An easy fix is to check the contents of `string` in your `write` function, and see if it contains any data:

```
def write(self, string):
    string = string.strip()
    if len(string) > 0:
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

@jro is right. `print` is sending `"hello\n"` in two shots through stdout.

Then, another still easier fix (despite maybe less convenient) is to end your `print`s with a comma:

```
print 'hello',
```

works because the comma tells `print` to stay in the same line.